# How do I disable git's credential helper for a single repository?

Tags: git

If I have a credential helper set in my `~/.gitconfig`, how can I disable/bypass it in a specific repo and use *no* credential helper?

I've tried editing the repo's `.git/config` file to blank out the `credential.helper` property like this:

```
[credential]
    helper =
```

... but when I do a `git push` I get the following error message, and Git uses my default credential helper from `~/.gitconfig` anyway:

```
git: 'credential-' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        credential
```

I'm using git version 1.7.12.

(Backstory/use case: Git is configured to use the `store` helper, which stores passwords unencrypted on disk. The `cache` helper is unavailable on this system. I have a couple repos for which I'd rather type the password every time than keep it on disk.)

Comment: Note: with git 2.9 (June 2016), your initial solution would have worked. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36435803/6309)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With git 2.9 (June 2016), this (`helper =` ) will actually work!

The `credential.helper` configuration variable is cumulative and there is no good way to override it from the command line.
As a special case, **giving an empty string as its value now serves as the signal to clear the values specified in various files**.

See [commit 2432137](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24321375cda79f141be72d1a842e930df6f41725) (26 Feb 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b68962](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b68962b29e39b0455e0f15d6b95edc65accb98c), 03 Apr 2016)</sup>

> ### `credential`: let empty credential specs reset helper list

> Since the `credential.helper` key is a multi-valued config list, there's no way to "unset" a helper once it's been set. So if your system `/etc/gitconfig` sets one, you can never avoid running it, but only add your own helpers on top.
>
> Since an empty value for `credential.helper` is nonsensical (it would just try to run "`git-credential-`"), we can assume nobody is using it. Let's define it to reset the helper list, letting you override lower-priority instances which
> have come before.

---

Even more convenient: With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), this override applies even for any value.

See [commit 46fd7b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46fd7b390034eb5dde6a3f955e677c5260e4d10c), [commit 82eb249](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82eb249853868582d8ba65e3afc5a7dcaeb620ea), [commit 588c70e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/588c70e10f3511f85110512da97b188f3c581e53), [commit 732f934](https://github.com/git/git/commit/732f93440831a9253ad5b9bd16a81e25e1901f22), [commit 3fa0e04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3fa0e046679b69ee7039a60674e9b16f83780e85) (20 Feb 2020) by [brian m. carlson (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2cbb058](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cbb0586697585995908c325a0c70aad37602274), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82eb249853868582d8ba65e3afc5a7dcaeb620ea): use the last matching username in the config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> Everywhere else in the codebase, we use the rule that the last matching configuration option is the one that takes effect.
>
> This is helpful because it allows more specific configuration settings (e.g., per-repo configuration) to override less specific settings (e.g., per-user configuration).
>
> **However, in the credential code, we didn't honor this setting, and instead picked the first setting we had, and stuck with it**.
>
> This was likely to ensure we picked the value from the URL, which we want to honor over the configuration.
>
> It's possible to do both, though, so let's check if the value is the one we've gotten over our protocol connection, which if present will have come from the URL, and keep it if so.
>
> Otherwise, let's overwrite the value with the latest version we've got from the configuration, so we keep the last configuration value.

---

Note: [user202729](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5267751/user202729) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198143/how-do-i-disable-gits-credential-helper-for-a-single-repository/36435803#comment121539523_36435803):

> If credential helper `A` is set as global and you want to use `B` in a *local* repository (*change*, not remove the helper), use:
>
> ```
> git config --local credential.helper ''
> git config --local --add credential.helper B
> ```
>
> The first empty item removes the global setting `A`.
>
> Equivalently, set two lines `helper =` and `helper = B` in `.git/config`.

Comment: Interestingly, e.g. `git -c credential.helper="" ls-remote https://github.com/heremaps/foobar.git` still does not work for me as it prompts for credentials.

Comment: @sschuberth What would a `git -c credential.helper="" config  credential.helper` return then? (and what version of Git are you using, on which OS?)

Comment: Well, as described at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_configuration_options setting `credential.helper` to an empty string should "resets the helper list to empty", so your command should return nothing. I also tried the alternative syntax of `git -c credential.helper=` (without the quotes), but that also does not work. I'm using Git for Windows 2.21.

Comment: @sschuberth Yes, it should return nothing, but in your case, what does it return? manager?

Comment: @sschuberth Because in my case (W10 1709, Git 2.21) `git -c credential.helper="" config credential.helper` returns nothing.

Comment: It returns nothing (as expected) for me, too, but still the concrete example of `git -c credential.helper="" ls-remote https://github.com/heremaps/foobar.git` prompts.

Comment: @sschuberth I suspect something else would prompt for those credentials. Is this a private repo?

Comment: No, it's simply a non-existing repository. I was hoping to be able to use `ls-remote` for probing GitHub repositories for existence non-interactively, but it seems this is not possible.

Comment: @sschuberth I confirm the credential helper is disabled. The credentials asked are *not* asked by the credential helper.

Comment: And I just verified that `git-gui--askpass` actually gets invoked in my case.

Comment: @sschuberth Maybe another approach like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450693/6309 would prove be a better fit?

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for this interesting feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 34):

What I've tried, and had worked well was:

```
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

But in order to that works fine, I had to set git-bash.exe with Administrator rights.

Unfortunately, I think this is a global variable. You should test and see if it works for single repositories.

Good luck

Comment: This actually helped me to solve the problem with git using the wrong user identity to auth to github (which made every attempt to push fail). I'll have to see if this affects another github account which uses an SSH key though...

Comment: I needed `git config --unset credential.helper` the value was being stored in a repo....but using both is what fixed my issue with and without `--system`

Comment: Is there a way to revert back to original after I used this command?

Comment: Thank for you this! Today I spent an entire morning trying to figure out why CredentialHelperSelector keeps popping up every time I fetch, despite me 
selecting `manager` and checking the _Always use this..._ checkbox every time. Your suggestion is what finally did the trick.

Answer (score 28):

In addition of '`git config credential.helper=`' that [I mention above with Git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435803/6309), you now (Git 2.13.x/Git 2.14, Q3 2017) can disable the credential helper just for one *command* (and not just for any command in a given repo)

That means `git -c credential.helper= clone /url/remote/repo` now works.

"`git clone --config var=val`" is a way to populate the
per-repository configuration file of the new repository, but **it did not work well when val is an empty string**.
This has been fixed.

See [commit db4eca1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db4eca1feaafa0669b7ba64c10314dfe8836576a) (02 May 2017) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 883247c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/883247c2fc1783b448fb8730284de85a758dc05d), 16 May 2017)</sup>

> ### `clone`: handle empty config values in `-c`
>
> "`git clone --config`" uses the following incantation to add an item to a config file, instead of replacing an existing value:
>
> ```
> git_config_set_multivar_gently(key, value, "^$", 0)
> ```
>
> As long as no existing value matches the regex `^$`, that works as intended and adds to the config.  When a value is empty, though, it replaces the existing value.
>
> Noticed while trying to set `credential.helper` during a clone to use a specific helper without inheriting from `~/.gitconfig` and `/etc/gitconfig`.
>   That is, I ran:
>
> ```
> git clone -c credential.helper= \
>      -c credential.helper=myhelper \
>      https://example.com/repo
> ```
>
> intending to produce the configuration:
>
> ```
> [credential]
>      helper =
>      helper = myhelper
> ```
>
> Without this patch, the '`helper =`' line is not included and the credential helper from `/etc/gitconfig` gets used.

---

Note that the documentation is now clearer with [commit 515360f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/515360f9e9be976344e3d21cf6f28dcd2ff3c4f9):

credential doc: make multiple-helper behavior more prominent

> Git's configuration system works by reading multiple configuration files in order, from general to specific:

- first, the system configuration `/etc/gitconfig`
- then the user's configuration (`~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config`)
- then the repository configuration (`.git/config`)

> For single-valued configuration items, the latest value wins.
>   For multi-valued configuration items, values accumulate in that order.
>
> For example, this allows setting a credential helper globally in `~/.gitconfig` that git will try to use in all repositories, regardless of whether they additionally provide another helper.
>   This is usually a nice thing --- e.g. I can install helpers to use my OS keychain and to cache credentials for a short period of time globally.
>
> Sometimes people want to be able to override an inherited setting.
>   **For the `credential.helper` setting, this is done by setting the configuration item to empty before giving it a new value**.

Comment: `git -c credential.helper= clone /url/remote/repo` works fine on git bash but it still asks for credentials while using powershell on windows.

Comment: @ybalcanci Strage. What git version are you using? (in Powershell, to be sure)

Comment: git version 2.25.0.windows.1. I think when a configuration's value is empty string, it might be inheriting that value from global configuration. But Idk why it is specific to powershell.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, the error I got was due to a typo in git bash. So, powershell and git bash behaviors match in this case. But I don't understand why `git clone -c credential.helper= https://bitbucket.org/user/repo.git master` asks for credentials. I want it to raise an error directly, because I am not authenticated and credential helper is undefined.

Answer (score 19):

A config variable that is set to an empty string is not the same as an unset variable. It is not possible to force a variable to be unset in `.git/config` when it is already set in `~/.gitconfig`.

Additionally `credential.helper` is one of these variables where multiple values are used, and in such cases the values are aggregated from all read config files.

So basically your options seem to be:

- either do not use `credential.helper` in `~/.gitconfig`; set the store helper only for the repositories where you want it, either in their `.git/config`, or in `~/.gitconfig` by specifying the repo URLs, eg.

  ```
  [credential "https://specific.example.com/repo.git"]
  helper = store
  ```
- or implement your own helper that does nothing for a set of configured repositories and delegates to `git credential-store` for the rest.

Comment: To enable the credential store for a single repository edit `.git/config` and add:
`[credential]
 helper = store`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem as well, as the first credential.helper I had configured was always executing when I wanted to test a new one. This is on macOS using git supplied with Apple's dev tools.

Listing the configs with `git config --list` showed both helpers.

Running `git config --global --edit` did not show the setting for the first helper. It's a little strange that --global when configuring the helper is not the same scope as --global while editing the configs.

Also since it I wanted to include a different helper, just blanking it out wasn't going to solve it.

Finally found the setting in two places:

- `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig`
- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig`

Removed the credential section from the first one, but both settings were still listed using `--list`. After rebooting and trying every combo of unset, unset-all --system, --global, et, I found the second file.

Removed the setting from that file (again was only one) and finally `--list` does not show any helpers configured.