# How do I make powershell stop showing this message whenever I push

Tags: github

How do I make powershell stop showing the below message:

> github --credentials get: github: command not found

This occurs whenever I try to `ssh` for `git push` or `git pull`.

Comment: Did you mean to use `git` instead of `github`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you git remote -v: it you see https, it is not an ssh url.
Make sure push or pull are using an ssh url with:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

If you are using https, Git will try and use a credential helper: see if `git config -l | grep cred` returns anything. That would explain the `github: command not found` part.

If you have, go to your repo and type:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config credential.helper ""
```

If your git is recent enough ([Git 2.9+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435803/6309)), that will prevent any credential helper to be active in your repo.

Comment: Basically what's happening is this:

Comment: And what i wanted to do is I just want it to stop displaying this after i use git pull or git push. I'm not really sure what I need to change for this to stop essneitally.

Comment: @HongyuWang What git config -l returns? Is there any credential.helper in there?

Comment: crednetial.helper=cache

Comment: I just used git config --global --unset-all crednetial.helper but the issue still persists

Comment: @HongyuWang I have edited the answer with a way to desactivate the credential helper.