# git -permission denied(403)

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using someone else's computer, and I cloned my own repository to this computer, and started working on it.
But when I was trying to push it:

```
$ git push origin master
```

it says:

```
remote: Permission to MyNewAccount/Project.git denied to SomeOneElsesAccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MyNewAccount/Project/': The 
requested URL returned error: 403
```

So basically I just need to change the default user name and user passport, which is now still the other guy's, right? But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Add the other guy as a contributor? Check the windows credential manager.

Comment: Use the `ssh` URL, not the HTTPS for push.

Answer (score 1):

Check the git global config: if you see a `credential.helper` set to `manager`, that means the credentials are store in the Windows Credential Store (see [Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)).

To make sure you don't use that credential helper, set it to "" ([since Git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435803/6309)) just for your repo

```
cd c:\path\to\my\repo
git config credential.helper ""
```

That will prevent the global one to be active, and allow you to enter your username and password.