# Git refuses to push after restart

Tags: git, github

I created a repository today locally, on my USB, and then pushed it to Github. Before I restarted whenever I typed `git push -u origin master` it would ask for my credentials and then push my changes.

**How would I set git to automatically enter them and just push it to the repo?**

After I restarting, when I type `git push -u origin master` it returns an error

> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

**What is causing this error and how do I fix it?**

Comment: are u in *nix machine?

Comment: Not enough details? if you have keys already.. you may just want to do ss-add ~/.ssh/somekey (ssh-add -- adds private key identities to the authentication agent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-asking-me-for-my-ssh-key-passphrase)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `automatically enter your credentials` you can setup [SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) which are a way of secure, automatic authentication.

If you correctly do that, it should fix your `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Comment: So after I posted I added an SSH key and did "git push -u origin (Github repo)" it asked for my credentials and logged me in, will I have to do this every time?

Comment: If you setup the SSH Key correctly, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: If it were me, I'd move the repository to my machine and make sure I wasn't doing anything to [disable gits credential helper for a single repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198143/how-do-i-disable-gits-credential-helper-for-a-single-repository/13203623#13203623)