# Using git in windows over sshd - stuck in push

Tags: windows, git, sshd

In my environment, I cannot log in to the Windows GUI, but I have to use sshd to get a console (cmd.exe) from windows server 2019. Git is installed, but as soon as I try to do a git push, I face a problem:

Usually, in a CMD Console in Windows, a window with the credential manager would pop up, which doesn't work for this use case, where I actually "ssh-ed" via putty to a windows server. It seems that git gets stuck, obviously wanting to open a window.

How can I turn off this behavior, and make git on Windows more "unix-ish", so that like in a Linux environment the username/password prompt appears on the console?

Comment: try to use credentials manager https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

Comment: Maybe using openssh as your SSH instead of putty could help you. It should be something in git config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and [disable the credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36435803/6309) (in your SSH session)

```
git config credential.helper=
```

That will allow you to test if Git is asking for credentials on the command line instead of opening a popup.
Note that this is only if you are cloning HTTPS URL.

Alternative option:

```
cd path/to/repo
git config --system --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: throws an error: git config credential.helper=
git config credential.helper=""
error: invalid key: credential.helper=

Comment: @Mandragor What version of Git do you have on that server you ssh'ed into?

Comment: git --version
git version 2.24.1.windows.2

Comment: @Mandragor OK. Then simply remove that setting (I have edited the answer), for testing.

Comment: your  alternative option "git config --system --unset credential.helper"   at least made it work on the console, but i am now confused, as it doesn't get stuck anymore, but also doesn't ask for my credentials and it simply works...

Comment: @Mandragor Is your remote repo a public one? If yes, there is no credentials required on cloning/pulling. On pushing, credentials are required only on HTTPS URLS, not SSH ones.

Comment: @Mandragor Is your remote repo URL an HTTPS one or an SSH one?

Comment: @Mandragor And it does not require any credential on git push?

Comment: no. as i cannot reboot the server right now, i suspect that the credential manager still somehow in the background provides the username / password, as i did not persist it on this server manually

Comment: @Mandragor a `git config --list --show-origin` should show you if there are any credential.helper still set.

Comment: yes you are right.  still found an entry in the .gitconfig  in my home directory.  removed it and yes,  finally the username / password request appears on the console!