# Git keeps storing credentials in Windows Credential Manager

Tags: windows, git, credentials, git-credential-manager

I'd like to use some git credentials for only single command.

`git -c remote.origin.url="http://pass:user@gitserver/GitRepo" push`

But after doing that credentials are saved in Credential Manager (i can see them in Windows Credential Manager), and are used implicitly for the subsequent `git push` commands.

How do I prevent storing them?

Comment: Add `-c credential.helper=` to your command line - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033298/1871033) in linked question.

Comment: Yeah, that works, it asks about credentials then which is not ideal (I gave it as an `-c` argument) but it will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### First, determine your scope

You might want to disable the use of the Windows Credential Manager in one of three different scopes:

- globally, so these creds are never stored in the manager,
- locally, so the creds are not stored in the manager for this one repo, or
- temporarily, for just one command.

In all cases, the answer is to unset the `credential.helper` in your configuration, but how you do it depends on the scope.

##### Globally

Run

```
git config --global credential.helper ""
```

and Git will no longer store credentials anywhere for you.

##### Locally

Once you've cloned a sandbox, you can disable the credential manager for operations inside that sandbox only with this command:

```
git config --local credential.helper ""
```

##### For one command only

Finally, you can use `-c` on the command line for one time overrides:

```
git -c credential.helper= <some command>
```

##### Locally, revisited

If you're going to disable credential management for a single repo, you'll actually have to use the `-c` variant when you clone the repo, to turn off credential storage on clone, and the `--local` setting in that sandbox, to turn off credential storage on push/pull/fetch operations.

##### Undoing it all

If you change your mind later, you can undo things by removing your own config setting that disables credential management:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

or

```
git config --local --unset credential.helper
```

This way, you go back to the system default (that's `manager-core` in my Git for Windows configuration, which uses the Windows Credential Manager).

Or, you can set your own credential manager choice explicitly, globally or in the sandbox, with:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

or

```
git config --local credential.helper manager-core
```